# Lie functor produces an antihomomorphism in Lavendhomme's synthetic differential geometry text?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, synthetic-differential-geometry

Classically the Lie functor maps a Lie group homomorphism to a Lie algebra homomorphism. But in Proposition 15 on page 249 in [Basic Concepts of Synthetic Differential Geometry](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792339410), Lavendhomme states that if $\alpha: G \to \text{Diff}(M)$ is a left action (a group homomorphism) then $T_e \alpha: \frak{g} \to \frak{X}$$(M)$ is an antihomorphism of Lie algebras.

It seems that this is not a typo, and he proves that this is indeed the case. Is there something I'm missing here?

If $G$ is a Lie group (a microlinear group), then the Lie algebra consists of all $X: D \to G$ such that $X(0)=e$. Here $D = \{ d \in \mathbb{R} : d^2 =0 \}$ is the "walking tangent vector." The Lie bracket of $X, Y \in \frak{g}$ is then defined to be the unique element $[X, Y] \in \frak{g}$ such that $$[X, Y](d_1 \cdot d_2) = Y(-d_2) \cdot X(-d_1) \cdot Y(d_2) \cdot X(d_1)$$
for any $d_1, d_2 \in D$. If $\text{Diff}(M)$ is microlinear, then the tangent space at $\text{id}_M$ is $\frak{X}$$(M)$, so this defines the Lie bracket on vector fields as well. This appears to be equivalent to the usual definition of the Lie bracket in terms of flows.

Comment: It means one or more (really, an odd number) of the author's conventions are weird; for example, maybe their definition of the Lie bracket on vector fields is the opposite of the usual one. Can you reproduce the proof? You can see another author saying the obvious thing, for example, here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/action.pdf (Theorem 1.11).

Comment: If the book defines the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ and on vector fields in this same uniform way then I can't imagine how it possibly gets an antihomomorphism out of a morphism of groups. Can you quote some more text from the book? I still think there's just a weird convention somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I figure one of his conventions differ from the ones I'm used to,  but I can't seem to figure out what it is exactly. I'll check his convention for the action of vector fields on smooth functions when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went back to Lavendhomme, and realized that this is a legitimate phenomenon which isn't really addressed in most books on classical differential geometry, because it isn't very obvious in this context.

Because of the common operator-theoretic approach to defining the tangent bundle and vector fields in classical differential geometry, we usually define the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ of vector fields $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ via commutators of their Lie derivatives $[\partial_X, \partial_Y]$.

But morally $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ should be the lie algebra of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ (and indeed it is in SDG), and so it has an intrinsic ``geometric'' Lie bracket defined via a group-theoretic commutator of infinitesimal flows. This geometric Lie bracket must actually be the *negative* of the commutator of Lie derivatives, i.e.
$$[X,Y]=-[\partial_X, \partial_Y].$$

This is because the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ of a smooth space $M$ acts on the *right* on $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$ by precomposition (pullback). This action is by algebra automorphisms, and so the infinitesimal action of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ on $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$ is by $\mathbb{R}$-linear derivations (i.e. Lie derivatives). But since it comes from a right action then this infinitesimal action must also be a right action, i.e. we have an *antihomomorphism* of Lie algebras
$$\mathfrak{X}(M) \to \operatorname{Der}_\mathbb{R}(C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})).$$

In SDG we can define the Lie bracket on the tangent space of a Lie monoid/group using a concrete formula without reference to vector fields, and we see that this bracket reproduces the geometric bracket of vector fields $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ when the latter are viewed as the tangent space at the identity of the automorphisms $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ of a space.

Regarding left and right invariant vector fields on a Lie monoid or group $G$, let $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra, and given $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, let's write $X_L, Y_L$ for the corresponding left-invariant vector field, and $X_R, Y_R$ for the corresponding right-invariant vector field. Then
$$[X,Y]=[X_R, Y_R]=[\partial_{X_L}, \partial_{X_L}].$$
So the Lie bracket of a lie algebra agrees with geometric bracket of right-invariant vector fields, and the operator-theoretic bracket of left-invariant vector fields.